# приложение на monodevelop, проблема с npgsql.dll

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, mono, monodevelop

Под Ubuntu установил *Mono Develo*p, *Postgresql*, *pgAdmin*.
Добавил несколько таблиц в *Postgresql* (localhost).
Для начала хочу написать простое приложение, типа *Windows Forms* или консольное, чтобы оно выводило полученный результат от запроса в *Postgre*.
В качестве запросов планирую использовать *LINQ*.

**Вопрос**: как подружить *MonoDevelop* и *Postgresql*?
Знаю, нужно добавить библиотеку *Npgsql.dll* и прописать зависимости.
Как узнать свою *.Net Framework* на *Ubuntu*?

Answer (score 0):

Версию .NET можно посмотреть/изменить в свойствах проекта (не решения), которые можно открыть либо двойным щелчком на названии проекта в решении в список слева, либо в меню проект->Параметры "ваш_проект".
В открывшемся окне в разделе Сборка->Общие выпадающий список "Целевая платформа".
Но, вероятно, на этом ваши проблемы не закончатся.